# Поиск по вложенным элементам в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Задание тестовое и не имеет под собой практической подоплеки, поэтому необходимо именно решение.

Имеется примерно такая структура:

```
dict = {key1 : [(value111, value112), (value121, value122)], 
        key2 : [(value211, value212), (value221, value222), (value231, value232)]}
```

Нужно проверить есть ли какое-то определенное значение в качестве второго элемента вложенного кортежа для всех элементов в листе. Кроме множественных вложенных `for` циклов красивого решения не получилось.

Comment: Приведите пример структуры, где такое значение имеет. А то как-то не очень понятно, что нужно найти.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то решение может быть таким:

```
dict = {'key1' : [('value111', 'value112'), ('value121', 'value122')], 
    'key2' : [('value211', 'value212'), ('value221', 'value222'), ('value231', 'value232')]}

def seekelem(search:str):
    for key in dict.keys():
        _, seq = zip(*dict[key])
        if search in seq:
            return f"Element {search} found in {key}"

#проверяем:        
print(seekelem('value222'))
```

> Element value222 found in key2

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

[True for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(dict.values()) if i[1] == value222]
```